# Does devise_token_auth use JSON web tokens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, devise-token-auth

I am creating a new SPA with a REST API and for the backend I am using Rails with devise_token_auth. I am new to token authentication and while searching I am seeing a lot of libraries for frontend libraries that support JWT but I can't tell if this is compatible with devise_token_auth.

Is JWT the standard for web tokens and is it what devise_token_auth uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `devise_token_auth` gem doesn't use JWT.

> It authenticates a user by validating the `client-id, access-token &
>   UID` and processes the request. All these keys are received during a
>   successful login.

Comment: Where did you find that quoted text?

Comment: @Qwertie https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/controller-integration#authentication-headers-example